# Aadd a formula/function to an excell cell from VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I need to add formula into a cell using a variable within VBA Code below:

```
Sub begin()

ActiveCell.Offset(5, 0).Select
ActiveCell = "Nombre d'appels"
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
Myrange = ("A2" & ":" & "A" & maxrow)
ActiveCell = "=COUNTA" & "(" & (Myrange) & ")"
ActiveCell.Offset(1, -1).Select
ActiveCell = "Appels abandonnés"
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
Myrange = ("Q2" & ":" & "Q" & maxrow)
ActiveCell = "=COUNTIF" & "(" & (Myrange) & ";" & "yes" & ")"
End Sub
```

This example shows COUNTA and COUNTIF. For COUNTA it is working properly with no errors.
As for countif it gives me a 1004 runtime error.

maxrow and Myrange are defined at higher level in the code.

Comment: `;` ------------> `,`

Comment: `"=COUNTIF(" & Myrange.Address & "; ""yes"")"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to count the occurrences of the string "yes", use

```
ActiveCell = "=COUNTIF" & "(" & (Myrange) & "," & """yes""" & ")"
```

while to count the occurrences of the value of any named range `yes`, use

```
ActiveCell = "=COUNTIF" & "(" & (Myrange) & "," & "yes" & ")"
```

Comment: I think it should be `"""yes"""`

Comment: Great thank you, it does not return the error code anymore, but does not take the YES as it should, and just returns 0 in the cell instead of 122 which is the current count of "yes".

Comment: A.S.H. you are right. That's it. thanks to both of you.

Comment: @A.S.H, from OP I couldn't say he wanted to reference a named range `yes` or the string "yes". Now he clarified and I'll edit the answer consequently